# Functor with wrong type argument

Tags: haskell

I have following datatype and had apply to `Functor` instance:

```
data Company a b c = 
    DeepBlue a c
  | Something b

instance Functor (Company a b) where 
  fmap f (Something b) = Something b
  fmap f (DeepBlue a c) = DeepBlue a (f c)
```

It gets compiled without any complains.

Then I played a bit around(I know it does not work), because of beginner curiosity:

```
data Company a b c = 
    DeepBlue a c
  | Something b

instance Functor (Company a b) where 
  fmap f (Something b) = Something (f b)
  fmap f (DeepBlue a c) = DeepBlue a (f c)
```

Then the compiler complains:

```
D:\haskell\chapter16\src\ChapterExercises.hs:18:26: error:
    * Couldn't match type `b1' with `b'
      `b1' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          fmap :: forall a1 b1.
                  (a1 -> b1) -> Company a b a1 -> Company a b b1
        at D:\haskell\chapter16\src\ChapterExercises.hs:18:3
      `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the instance declaration
        at D:\haskell\chapter16\src\ChapterExercises.hs:17:10
      Expected type: Company a b b1
        Actual type: Company a b1 b1
    * In the expression: Something (f b)
      In an equation for `fmap': fmap f (Something b) = Something (f b)
      In the instance declaration for `Functor (Company a b)'
    * Relevant bindings include
        b :: b
          (bound at D:\haskell\chapter16\src\ChapterExercises.hs:18:21)
        f :: a1 -> b1
          (bound at D:\haskell\chapter16\src\ChapterExercises.hs:18:8)
        fmap :: (a1 -> b1) -> Company a b a1 -> Company a b b1
          (bound at D:\haskell\chapter16\src\ChapterExercises.hs:18:3)

D:\haskell\chapter16\src\ChapterExercises.hs:18:39: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `a1' with actual type `b'
      `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the instance declaration
        at D:\haskell\chapter16\src\ChapterExercises.hs:17:10
      `a1' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          fmap :: forall a1 b1.
                  (a1 -> b1) -> Company a b a1 -> Company a b b1
        at D:\haskell\chapter16\src\ChapterExercises.hs:18:3
    * In the first argument of `f', namely `b'
      In the first argument of `Something', namely `(f b)'
      In the expression: Something (f b)
    * Relevant bindings include
        b :: b
          (bound at D:\haskell\chapter16\src\ChapterExercises.hs:18:21)
        f :: a1 -> b1
          (bound at D:\haskell\chapter16\src\ChapterExercises.hs:18:8)
        fmap :: (a1 -> b1) -> Company a b a1 -> Company a b b1
          (bound at D:\haskell\chapter16\src\ChapterExercises.hs:18:3)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

What does the compiler try say?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've declared `Company` as type with three generic types, `a`, `b`, and `c`. When you create an instance `instance Functor (Company a b)` you've said that for any `a` and `b`, there should exist a function `fmap` with the type:

```
(c -> d) -> Company a b c -> Company a b d
```

The function `f` has the type `c -> d`, so you can't use `b` as input for it, because it doesn't have the correct type.

Answer (score 2):

Your definition of `fmap` has type

```
fmap :: Company a b c -> (c -> d) -> Company a b d
```

so the function takes a value of type `c`. In

```
fmap f (Something b) = Something (f b)
```

you are attempting to apply a function `c -> d` to a value of type `b` which causes the error. The actual type variables in the message have different names: `a1` is  `c` and `b1` is `d`